# Differential operators and vector fields

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-operators

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. It is well known that there is a bijective correspondance between vector fields on $M$ and differential operators of order 1. My question is: if we take a differential operator of order larger than $1$, what is the "corresponding object" ?

Comment: You can form tensors of any desired rank.

Comment: perhaps you want jet bundles?

Comment: The "well known" bit isn't quite correct, I think because of a slight misunderstanding of the "order" of a differential operator: order is a *filtration*, not a *grading*. The idea still makes some sense, however, and the correction points the way to a correct answer: instead of looking for something corresponding to the operator itself, look for something in the *associated graded algebra*. The relevant concept is the **principal symbol**.